# Excel pivot diagram is way too wide

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, diagrams

Every time I refresh my pivot diagram, the diagram expands and becomes as wide as four times the screen width.

How do I stop it from acting crazy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Pivot Table Options (right-click in table), uncheck "Autofit columns on update" in the Format and Layout tab (first tab)

Comment: thank you so much, didn't know that affected the pivot diagram too, would have never figured out!